# Bluetooth does not work on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13 with an Intel 8260 wireless card

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, intel

Wireless works fine, and bluetooth was working earlier when I had 16.04 as the Ubuntu version.

The card supports both bluetooth and wireless:

Intel Network 8260.NGWMG Wireless-AC 8260 Dual Band 2x2 AC + Bluetooth vPro Brown Box